# Getting IllegalArgumentException when navigating with NavController in Android: How to resolve this crash?

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, uinavigationcontroller

I am facing an IllegalArgumentException when trying to navigate the with NacController.
here is the detail of crash

```
`Exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate (NavController.kt:1540)
at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate (NavController.kt:1472)
at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate (NavController.kt:1454)
at com.nexusai.chataigbt.utils.Utils.fragmentNavigate (Utils.kt:43)
at com.example.fragments.HomeFragment$getHistory$1$1.invoke (HomeFragment.kt:274)
at com.example.fragments.HomeFragment$getHistory$1$1.invoke (HomeFragment.kt:266)
at com.example.adapter.SessionAdapter.onBindViewHolder$lambda$0 (SessionAdapter.kt:43)
at com.example.adapter.SessionAdapter.$r8$lambda$ZoflL_Pg09axtHG1MJ0uW27xFpc
at com.nexusai.chataigbt.adapter.SessionAdapter$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onClick
at android.view.View.performClick (View.java:6314)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run (View.java:24793)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:790)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:164)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6543)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:440)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:810)`
```

**Code**

```
   fun Fragment.fragmentNavigate(currentId: Int, destinationId: Int) {
        try {
            if (findNavController().currentDestination?.id != currentId) {
                findNavController().navigate(destinationId)
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
```

Comment: please share the code that leads to the crash. Thanks

Comment: Please share a code snippet to elaborate your question

Comment: @Lino I did edit the question